# Using Typhoon, create instance of a subclass of a class which has dependencies

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection, typhoon

I am using [Typhoon](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon) for dependencies injection in Swift for iOS.

I have created an assembly to inject dependencies in a class called BaseRequest like this:

```
public class NetworkAssembly: TyphoonAssembly {
    public dynamic func baseRequest() -> AnyObject {
        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(BaseRequest.self){
            (definition) in
            definition.useInitializer("initWithRetryCount:userUmbrella:networkQueueManager:"){
                (initializer) in

                initializer.injectParameterWith((TyphoonConfig("network.request.retry.count") as! NSNumber).integerValue)
                initializer.injectParameterWith(self.coreComponents.userUmbrella())
                initializer.injectParameterWith(self.networkQueueManager())

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to create a subclass of BaseRequest with a factory method like this:

```
class DownloadLibrariesRequest: BaseRequest {
    var libraries:Array<String> = []

    class func downloadLibraries(libraries:Array<String>)->Void{
        let request: DownloadLibrariesRequest = DownloadLibrariesRequest(.....)
        request.libraries = libraries
    }
}
```

I need to be able to create an instance of **DownloadLibrariesRequest** and call the **NetworkAssembly** for **BaseRequest** since I need to use another init in the subclasses.
Also, I need to mention that I will have around 50 such subclasses, so creating assemblies for all of them doesn't sound too great at the moment.

Comment: DI sounds like an awful lot of work for questionable benefit. Why not take advantage of Swift's built-in language features, like protocols, generics, and constrained extensions?

Comment: It shouldn't be a lot of work, not really, not if you use a 3rd party at least. The main benefit for me is a more decoupled code which makes for a much more clear code on large projects. As a disadvantage, it looks to me like it's much harder to debug such code.

Comment: Too many levels of indirection make things difficult to reason about, which is especially important in a large code base. There's also a performance cost for this kind of abstraction. I'd strongly encourage you to take a look at some of the Swift sessions from WWDC this year, to get a better idea of the new and existing language features.

Comment: @mattt 2016 WWDC talks about the benefits of dependency injection

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/213/?time=1146

Answer (score 0):

To create a definition with shared configuration, in order to avoid repetition, use the [parent](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Types-of-Injections#abstract-and-base-definitions) feature.